# OledbException row-00001 cannot allocate memory

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oledb

I am trying to get data from a oracle database using c#. I was using System.Data.OracleClient.dll but since this is obsolete i decided to change this to System.Data.Oledb.
My connection:

```
connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password=23};", source, user, password);
```

Here is my method to get the data:

```
public ContactInfo GetInfo(string telnr)
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("OracleState: {0}", connection.State);
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        string sql = @"Select t1.bed_bedrijfsnr
                      , t1.pers_persoonsnr
                      , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.telefoonnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') as telnr
                      , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.gsmnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') as gsmnr
                      , t1.e_mail
                      , t2.synoniem
                      , t2.sales_coordinator
                    From table1 t1
                      , table2 t2
                    Where t1.bed_bedrijfsnr = t2.bedrijfsnr
                    And (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.telefoonnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = :tel Or REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.gsmnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = :tel);";
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":tel", telnr));

        ContactInfo c = null;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //readdata
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Oracle State: {0}", connection.State);
        return c;
    }
```

When i change the sql statement to "Select * from table1" it works but with this statement i visual studio says 'OledbException row-00001 cannot allocate memory' on 'OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it generates that particular error but when you use Parameters.Add it does not appear to substitute in for more than one parameter instance.

Since you use ":tel" twice in your SQL statement you need to use Parameters.Add twice. It seems to work fine if you reuse the same parameter name but I rename mine anyway.

```
string sql = @"Select t1.bed_bedrijfsnr
                  , t1.pers_persoonsnr
                  , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.telefoonnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') as telnr
                  , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.gsmnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') as gsmnr
                  , t1.e_mail
                  , t2.synoniem
                  , t2.sales_coordinator
                From table1 t1
                  , table2 t2
                Where t1.bed_bedrijfsnr = t2.bedrijfsnr
                And (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.telefoonnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = :tel1 Or REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.gsmnr, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = :tel2);";
command.CommandText = sql;
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":tel1", telnr));
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":tel2", telnr));
```